# Why does adding LIMIT to my query make it crawl?

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by, limits

Simple query:

```
select sum(score) total,name,gender,dob,country 
from users join scores on users.id = scores.user_id
where date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31 23:59:59'
group by scores.user_id having sum(score)>=1000 order by sum(score) desc limit 50
```

So trying to get a list of accumulated scores for Jan 2012, order them by scores descending and paginate them.

Without limit: slowish but OK: searches 69348 rows. (Be nice to work out how to avoid the temporary table but I can't). Explain says:

```
1, 'SIMPLE', 'scores', 'range', 'user,date,user+date', 'date', '8', '', 69348, 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'users', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '8', 'scores.user_id', 1, 'Using where'
```

With limit: it's the same but the rows search are now 1806794 and it takes forever.

It's a partitioned InnoDB if that makes any difference, with all data being on one partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to try:

Adding an index on `(user_id, date, score)`

Group by only on `scores` table and then join to `users`:

```
SELECT s.total, u.name, u.gender, u.dob, u.country
FROM users AS u
  JOIN 
  ( SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS total
    FROM scores
    WHERE date >= '2012-01-01' AND date < '2012-02-01'
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING SUM(score) >= 1000
    ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 50
  ) AS s
      ON u.id = s.user_id
ORDER BY total DESC ;
```

Comment: Thanks: yeah, for some reason I initially shyed away from using derived tables, but with a bit of tinkering, going down this route this has helped get better performance.

Answer (score 5):

Use correct ANSI group by (not the MySQL <strike>abomination</strike> extension) and see what happens

```
select sum(score) total,name,gender,dob,country  
from users join scores on users.id = scores.user_id
where date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31 23:59:59'
group by name,gender,dob,country
having sum(score)>=1000
order by sum(score) desc limit 50
```

Why?

GROUP BY in MySQL implies ORDER BY which causes the filesort here
Changing the query to be more standard *may* help the optimiser

More on the MySQL <strike>abominations</strike> extensions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6642253/27535
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10894876/27535
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6457144/27535

And from the MySQL [Docs on ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html)

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the WHERE clause. These cases include the following:
>
> ...
>
> You have different ORDER BY and GROUP BY expressions.

Comment: Cool: that got the explain rows down to the same as the first query. I'm marking the other answer as "best", but this has been really useful: coming from SQL Server, I new MySQL handled group by more laxly, but I didn't realise it had a potential effect of queries.